# How to read scope properties from parent scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

I am creating a simple directive however I am stuck at the beginning. My problem is that I am unable to read the property from scope in the post function. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/PkfJQ/1/) is my code:

```
   <div mod type="{{subnet.isDynamic | type }}"></div>


    networkInterfaces.directive('mod', function () {


    return {

        scope: {
            type: '@'
        },


        link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {


            console.log(scope.type);


            if (scope.type == "Static") {
                iElement.css('background', 'blue');
            }

            if (scope.type == "Dynamic") {
                iElement.css('background', 'green');
            }

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the problem with the question ? why do you down vote it ?

Comment: Interesting. Which version did you fix the issue with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scope property is really wrong and you don't need it here.

A working plnkr here : http://plnkr.co/edit/ezbzad?p=preview

Please refer to the docs for understand the scope property inside a directive : http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

But if you really want to use just do that :

```
    app.directive("mod", function(){

      return {
        scope: {
          value: "@value"
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
          console.log(scope.value);
        }
      }


});
```

the scope property with {} create a new isolate scope so you can't access to your value.
Adding value: "@value" the scope is bind to the value property but note that the syntax is a javascript object syntax it's :

`value : "@value"` and not `value = "@value"` !!!

Oh and a last thing : if your directive is call `mod` ... in your div **your attribute is** `mod` **not** `someDirective`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it obviously works, however not in my case ! I tried it in my code but it didn't work and I don't know :)

Comment: If in the scope property you do { internalValue: "@value" } then you have to console.log(scope.internalValue). Do you understand ?

Comment: Yes I do Understand it pretty well ! It still does not work moreover in your example you don't have any scope:{prop:'@value'} at all !

Comment: Try to change scope{ type: "@" } to scope {type : "@type" }

Comment: Oh the "|" is for filter not directive.

Comment: I forget to tell that I use my directive inside ng-repeat I don't think that this makes difference or does it ?

Comment: ok try to change scope { value: "@value" } by scope : { type: "=type" } so ... Anyway ask another question it's really different than this one !

Comment: I've been trying this for 3 hours now !!! nothing is working I really start to hate this Angular !

Comment: Lol ! Read the docs really whatc videos at egghead.io ! Anywxay if you remove the scope property it doesn't work ? and what is this filter "type" where is define ? Have you create a custom filter ?

Comment: well it was versions issue !